# Define CSS for li id

Tags: css

How do I define a style for an li id? Does it work the same way as an li style?

e.g.

```
<li id="news" class="section_wrapper"></li>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [ID selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors):

```css
#news { 
    color: red; 
}
```

If you want higher [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), you can combine both the element and ID selectors:

```css
li#news { 
    color: red; 
}
```

Comment: @Raynos: Y U PROMOTE FEAR MONGERING.

Comment: Seriously though, id's should never be used in CSS. it's a known [anti pattern](http://oli.jp/2011/ids/)

Comment: @Raynos: I don't see the point in adding markup (`class=""`) to an element just so I can apply styling to it.  Yes, ID selectors are less performant when they are combined with descendant/child selectors, and they have the second-highest order of specificity, but the latter can be a good thing. They are also the fastest selector when they are used alone. If elements already have IDs so I can select them easily with JavaScript or as URL anchors, then I'm certainly going to style them using ID selectors.

Comment: @Raynos Y U NO LET MAN ANSWER OP QUESTION?!?!?! FFS, he asked how to use ID's in CSS - you respond with DONT USE THEM.. turd.

Comment: @rlemon but that's the correct answer. COMMUNITY Y U NO PROMOTE BEST PRACTICES

Comment: aside from that i do agree- classes are better, but try to reason with the OP and give him examples of why that would appeal to him - not just because 'its a standard, that doesn't really break anything if you don't use it... just makes life more difficult'

Comment: @Raynos no it is not the correct answer. "Hey guis, how do I peel an apple?". you: "Dont peel it, slice it its better" you offered an opinion - not how to answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it's the same
you should add `li#news {/*style here*/}` in css

Answer (score 1):

IDs are represented by hashes. So instead of `li {`...

```
#news {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

```
<ol>
    <li id="news1" class="section_wrapper">Item 1</li>
    <li id="news2" class="section_wrapper">Item 2</li>
    <li id="news3" class="section_wrapper">Item 3</li>
</ol>

#news1 {
 background-color: red;   
}
```

here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqdfc/) that demonstrates it

**hope this helps**