# CSS ID are already defined

Tags: css

I'm using an `ul` with its own ID on the left side of my website and another `ul` with the same ID on the right side because I have 2 menus. The problem is that Firefox told me that I can't use the same ID for the right side because it is already defined.
That's how it is defined on CSS

```
#accordion {

}
```

and the HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion">
```

I found the same question on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488141/define-css-for-li-id) so I tried to define the menu to the left using

```
#accordion
```

and the menu to the right using

```
ul#accordion
```

but it crashes. How can I fix it?

Comment: You can change ID with class.

Comment: And you shouldn't re-use IDs on the same page...for this very reason.

Comment: bad html = bad results. don't re-use IDs.

Comment: So you have 2 HTML elements with the same ID on your page?  If so, that's a problem.  You should probably change it to a class.

Comment: Use class instead of id. <ul class="accordion">. The id is a unique identifier.

Comment: Yes I read about it. If I replace ID with class, menus crash. Should I replace all other `<li id="...">` with `<li class="..">`?

Comment: Just rename one to '#accordion2` and use the same styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what Firefox asked you: IDs are unique.
Read more on [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1):

the whole point of using ids is for them to be unique, maybe you should use class instead